# Charging 18650 3s5p

Tags: charging, bms

I am looking to build a 3s5p pack using LC18650 Samsung cells. The idea is to run my fiber/wifi router during power outages (south africa loadshedding +- 4h per day) directly from the pack and avoid using an inverter.

One of the things i would like for this is the pack should have a built in charger that is connected to the mains power supply, this should charge until the pack is full.

The cells are not protected cells as such i would need to add a BMS of some sort to prevent them overcharging, discharging, Balancing etc.

I found this [BMS board](https://www.banggood.com/3S-40A-Li-ion-Lithium-Battery-Charger-Protection-Board-PCB-BMS-With-Balance-p-1394450.html)

And i already have this [power supply](https://www.banggood.com/Geekcreit-AC-100-240V-to-DC-12V-5A-60W-Switching-Power-Supply-Module-Driver-Adapter-LED-Strip-Light-p-1441620.html)

My question is, if i connect up the power supply permanently to the BMS can i trust that it will charge the batteries to full and then stop? 
Or do i need to find some other sort of way to charge and balance the pack?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. This question deals with the use of a certain BMS and is off-topic here. If the datasheet of the BMS can't answer your questions, we can't probably either.

Comment: This is a protection board. It's not a charger. It even shows you on the diagram where to "Connect charger, load".

Comment: @Finbarr that is exactly why i am asking the question. In my mind if i connect a 12v power supply to the "Connect charger, load" would a BMS prevent the pack from being overcharged?

Comment: @Ariser i dont really care about the specifics of that BMS i added it to the post as bit of extra info to clarify the type of BMS i am looking at. My question is how do i go about achieving my goal, If a BMS is not what i need then i would like to understand why it is not what i need and what i should be looking for instead. Its clearly not off-topic in my eyes.

Comment: To charge Li-ion batteries you need a charger that controls the current. This isn't one, it's really just an emergency cut-off.

Comment: In any case, lead-acid batteries are far better suited to this sort of application as you can trickle charge them indefinitely. That's why most UPS systems use them.

Comment: @Daxxy: Then it seems to be a question asking for a product recommendation, which is off-topic as well. Think: What is the real engineering task and how would an EE try to solve it. Try to do it using block schematics and calculations, and if you get stuck, ask here again.